# Is MFC class CInternetConnection/CHttpConnection theadsafe

Tags: c++, mfc

I am pretty sure these classes are not thread safe.
But, is it safe to use different objects from these classes in different threads?
Do they have any global dependencies with each other like static data or anything to watch out for?

Answer (score -1):

As long as the calls you are making are to static functions that do not access shared memory (shared between threads).

Basically the only time you will hit a problem is if the function you call accesses shared data.  If your function simply does some work on data you provide it is thread safe.